# Vaadin scroolbars on window resizing

Tags: vaadin

When Im making browser's window smaller. I cant see all objects also there is no vertical and horizontal scroolbars. Can u guys share information with me how I can fix it.

Also there is no scroolbars, when my layout is out of screen resolution.

How I can add scroolbars by default when my layout out of screen resolution

Comment: the usual way is to wrap in a panel (as already answered in quite some ansers here).  could you please provide a minimal failing example for us.

Comment: @cfrick I am using AbsoluteLayout may be it causes problem?

Comment: First please give us your code - edit your question and paste problematic code. Then maybe I can help you. For now I can confirm, that AbsoluteLayout can make some problems. Here is similar problem on [Vaadin Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/682940/797075). Vertical and Horizontal layouts can have scrollbars without additional Panels.

Comment: @jsosnowski Vertical and Horizontal layout CANNOT have scrollbars. In Vaadin a Panel is always needed for scrollbars.

Comment: @HenriKerola Theoretically you are right. But I'm using Valo Theme and when I add style `v-scrollable` to `VerticalLayout` the scroll bars appears if layout content is too big. It can be weird but works and I found that style name in HTML of [this demo page](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!forms). Here is [source](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/25a7dabf8031f4678babf5d6ed8510c7a646a6e7/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tests/themes/valo/Forms.java) but it has neither `v-scrollable` nor `Panel`.